# How to put sequential number for each node (on one level) in TSQL, using .nodes()?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I need to expand an xml in SQL server as table. I do that using `XQuery` with `nodes()` and `.query()`. But I need that each node has a sequential number and I also need to filter nodes based on their internal structure and I don't figure out how to do that.

I need following result:

```
------------------------
| 1  | <xml node ...> |
------------------------
| 2  | <xml node ...> |
------------------------
...
```

I have following XML:

```
<node xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Domain</Tag>
        <Value>dom</Value>
    </subnode>
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Wdth</Tag>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </subnode>
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Code</Tag>
        <Value>TEST</Value>
    </subnode>
</node>
<node xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Domain</Tag>
        <Value>dom</Value>
    </subnode>
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Wdth</Tag>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </subnode>
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Code</Tag>
        <Value></Value>
    </subnode>
</node>
```

I need when `<Tag>Code</Tag>` has value empty (`<Value></Value>`) to skip this node.

I use the following code, but I can not figure out how to make sequential numbers or how to filter:

```
DECLARE @XMLInput XML = '<node xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Domain</Tag>
        <Value>dom</Value>
    </subnode>
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Wdth</Tag>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </subnode>
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Code</Tag>
        <Value>TEST</Value>
    </subnode>
</node>
<node xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Domain</Tag>
        <Value>dom</Value>
    </subnode>
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Wdth</Tag>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </subnode>
    <subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
        <Tag>Code</Tag>
        <Value></Value>
    </subnode>
</node>';

SELECT 
    Child.query('declare default element namespace "http://mynamespace.com/ns/"; (.)') AS node
FROM
        @XMLInput.nodes('declare default element namespace "http://mynamespace.com/ns/"; (/node)') AS N(Child)
```

**EDIT:**
Because there are unclear elements I clarify. I need to filter out entire `<node>` node when there is a `<subnode>` node with `<Tag>` node with value `"Code"` and corresponding `<Value>` node which is empty. In this case I need whole `<node>` to be removed - not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is rather easy, use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`. As XMLs have an implicit sort order, we can use `(SELECT NULL)`. Rows will appear according to their physical order within the XML:

With this code you will get your nodes numbered:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://mynamespace.com/ns/')
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NodeNr
      ,Child.query('.') AS node
FROM
    @XMLInput.nodes('/node') AS N(Child)
```

Your second part is not clear for me. Do you want to surpress the second node completely because there is

```
<subnode xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/ns/">
    <Tag>Code</Tag>
    <Value></Value>
</subnode>
```

? Or do you want to surpress just this `<subnode>`?

The following would use the upper as *derived table* (a `CTE`) and then use `.exist()` on the column `node`. This method merely checks the existance of any node according to the `XQuery` expression. In this case I search for any `<Tag>` with the `text()="Code"`. From there we navigate one level up and search for a `<Value>` element where the `text()` is empty. If this exists, the function returns `1`, so we need those without:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://mynamespace.com/ns/')
,shredded AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NodeNr
            ,Child.query(N'.') AS node
    FROM
        @XMLInput.nodes(N'/node') AS N(Child) 
)
SELECT *
FROM shredded
WHERE shredded.node.exist(N'//Tag[text()="Code"]/../Value[empty(text())]')=0
```

### UPDATE: Documentation of sort order persistance

As @MartinSmith has pointed out, there was no proof for this

> Rows will appear according to their physical order within the XML

In the meanwhile I've found this:

- I found a paper on [XML in SQL Server 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(v=sql.90).aspx). There you can find *XML values are stored in an internal format ... in order to support the XML model characteristics, such as document order ...* This is - at least - a hint, that the document's order is persisted. Reading XML with `FROM OPENXML` will return a sorted table too (at least I didn't find any exceptions yet).
- Further more I've found [Understanding the XML data type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522493(v=sql.105).aspx). where you can find *This internal representation includes information about the containment hierarchy, document order, and element and attribute values. Specifically, the InfoSet content of the XML data is preserved*.
- About [`InfoSet` I found this document](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/), which states about `[children]`: *An ordered list of child information items, in document order*.

Well, this is still no valid proof, that a `SELECT` on `.nodes()` will return the derived table in exactly the same order as *within* the XML under all circumstances. But - at least - it points to the fact, that the internal order is worth to be persisted.

My conclusio: The internal order is seen as inherent part of the XML document. That's why I'm pretty sure, that `.nodes()` will return a derived table in the same order. Adding `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` should do nothing else than to add a running number to these rows.

Comment: "Rows will appear according to their physical order within the XML". Can you find that documented?

Comment: I know about `ROW_NUMBER()`, but I was not aware that I can use it with `NULL` :). I want to suppress whole parent node. 10x

Comment: @new2ios Did you check my code? I think it does exactly what you need...

Comment: Sorry, @Shnugo. My mistake. I did not try code. 10x again.